# Applications configuration

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am developing a large app that actually is two apps in one.  One component will act as a server on an iPad.  The other will be a client on a iPhone/iTouch.  The two are dependent on one another...i.e. must have both to have a functioning app.

Question:  Do I create two separate apps and submit for approval noting the dependencies or can I create a single application set to be universal.  So when the user installs on a particular device they get the correct component?  Want to make sure the approval process through Apple goes smoothly.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that is totally up to you.

I would go with the universal app,less hassle for the user. But you might want to split them and make the iPad (server) paid and the client's free.

But this is all up to you and what you are planning to do with your app(s).

Comment: Thanks for the response rckones! I think I was more worried about getting it through the approval process.  Didn't know if there was a preferred way.

Comment: The approval process is not set in stone, I've had apps be reject where the same thing in my other apps was excepted. But for you concern about one or two apps there should not be any problems with the approval process.